# Why does the value range of outputs need to be restricted?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, protocol, transaction-verification, consensus, output

In the 'tx messages' section for [protocol rules](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_rules#.22tx.22_messages) we have

> 4. Each output value, as well as the total, must be in legal money range

> 12. For each input, if the referenced output does not exist (e.g. never existed or has already been spent), reject this transaction

If my understanding is correct, rule 4 will confirm 0 <= output, sum of outputs <= 21,000,000, and rule 12 is checking that each input is in the UTXO set. I am having a hard time seeing why rule 4 is necessary, it seems like other rules - such as rule 12 - would already invalidate a transaction that was not in legal range. No one could ever have > 21,000,000 bitcoin so there could never be utxos for more 21,000,000.

Also, where can I find the code for these checks in the [source code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin).

Comment: There's no real reason for the rule to exist, other than that there had been an integer overflow incident in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output value was only constrained by their sum being smaller than that of the inputs, you could e.g. set one output to a negative value and create new money in a second output.

You can also do more creative stuff:
I think the rule might have been introduced as a response to the [value overflow incident](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Value_overflow_incident) on 2010-08-15. A transaction in a (now invalid) block at height 74638 created outputs that were so large that their sum overflowed into the permitted range. The transaction created 2×92.2 billion bitcoins.

The code fix for the value overflow incident can be found in this [commit](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/d4c6b90ca3f9b47adb1b2724a0c3514f80635c84#diff-118fcbaaba162ba17933c7893247df3aR1013). The code for this rule can be found in [src/consensus/tx_check.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/c46f1ce75196860c8b036d2965faac7db3aa4414/src/consensus/tx_check.cpp#L30). The `CheckTransaction()` function checks consensus rules that don't require any knowledge of the current chainstate.